# How to remap oAuth2 response body for Java Webclient

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, webclient

I'm using Spring Webclient to make an API call to a service that is oAuth secured. To obtain the oAuth2 token, I am using the following to create a oAuth enabled webclient which prior to the API call obtains a token from an auth server:

```
      WebClient webClient(@Qualifier("cr") ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations) {
            
ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrations, new UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository());
            oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("myService");

            return WebClient.builder()
                        .filter(oauth)
                        .build();
      }
```

The issue is; the oAuth server issues a non-standard response where all field names use bumpy case as opposed to the expected underscore (eg; accessToken vs access_token, refreshToken vs refresh_token, etc). This breaks my code because the token parser does not find the attributes in the response body.

Is there a way to re-map my incoming response body? I'd think I should be able to attach a filter to my oauth object that was created but I haven't found anything yet that'd work.

Thanks for your help.